# Xamarin alpha and MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I have updated my version of Xamarin to alpha and now i have that error (this version must be resolve PCL...)

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.3/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:
>   Error: PCL Reference Assemblies not installed. (MyProject.Core)

That are my environment information

=== Xamarin Studio ===

Version 4.1.12 (build 6)
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.3 ((no/8d3b4b7)
    GTK+ 2.24.20 theme: Raleigh
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 5.0 (3332.25)
Build 5A1413

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 7.0.2.7 (Business Edition)
Branch: 
Build date: 2013-04-10 18:05:51-0400

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 4.8.3 (Business Edition)
    Supported Android versions:
        1.6   (API level 4)
        2.1   (API level 7)
        2.2   (API level 8)
        2.3   (API level 10)
        3.1   (API level 12)
        3.2   (API level 13)
        4.0   (API level 14)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.1   (API level 16)
        4.2   (API level 17)
Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-456-11M4508)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-456, mixed mode)

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Probably best to contact Xamarin support to ask what they've changed - that's why you pay them :/

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No Sam. I'm went back to stable :-(

Comment: We must open a ticket?